# jQuery applying multiple :not to a links

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to bind a click event to a clicks, but exclude ones that

1. Dont have href
2. Do not have the class `.ignore-a`
3. Do not have the data attribute `"data-ajax"` that equals `"off"`
4. And href value that equals `#`

For whatever reason, it doesn't work and still binds events. What have I done wrong in my selector?

```
    $(document.body).on('click', 'a[href]:not(.ignore-a):not([data-ajax="off"]):not([href="#"])', function(ev) {

        ev.preventDefault();

        var url = $(this).attr('href').replace(BASE_URL, '');
        ajaxLoader.fetchPage(url);

        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Your code is contradicting your exclude list. You need to clarify what you want to actually fire the event. Also, provide the code you're testing it with.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed by @Jecoms your selector is contradicting your exclude list.
From the latter I'd rather write merely:

```
'a.ignore-a[href][data-ajax="off"]:not([href="#"])'
```

Comment: But wouldn't that bind the events to things I don't want to bind them to?

Comment: @BenShepherd Based on your question, and if well understood it, no. To reword it, this selector binds only elements that: 1) are `<a>` tags with `href` attribute, unless when `href="#"`; 2) have a `ignore-a` class; 3) have `data-ajax="off"`.